# SQL INSERT statements

Tags: sql-server

The first piece of code represents a update statement that updates all existing columns rows to whatever the user wants. So then i wrote a select statement that grabbed all the columns that were null/not existing and it returns 63 rows without the end where statement but with it then returns 62 which are the ones that are NULL not existing. So now I need to convert the sql select that selects all NUll rows into a insert than puts data into those not existing records. so far I posted what i have. Why isn't this working? it is saying that column schoolDay does not exist, how do i input those fields?

```
update e
set e.type = @dayEvent 
from odb.dayEvent e
inner join odb.day d on e.dayID = d.dayID
inner join MMSD.vSchoolFromCalendar c on d.calendarID = c.calendarID
                                      and d.structureID = c.structureID
inner join odb.PeriodSchedule p on d.periodScheduleID = p.periodScheduleID
                                and d.structureID = p.structureID
where d.[date] between @toDate and @fromDate
  and datepart(dw, d.[date]) not in (1,7)
  and e.[type] != @dayEvent
  and DistrictCode = 'MA'
  and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear
  and summerSchool = '0'
  and left(SchoolCode, 1) = @schoolChoice
  and e.[type] != @dayEvent

select 
    sts = 'success', 
    result = convert(varchar, @@rowcount) + ' rows updated.';

set @rowcount = (select @@rowcount);    

select 
    d.schoolDay,
    d.instruction,
    d.attendance, 
    d.duration,
    d.comments,
    d.startTime, d.endTime,
    e.type
from 
    odb.dayEvent e
right outer join
    odb.day d on e.dayID = d.dayID
inner join 
    MMSD.vSchoolFromCalendar c on d.calendarID = c.calendarID
                               and d.structureID = c.structureID
inner join 
    odb.PeriodSchedule p on d.periodScheduleID = p.periodScheduleID
                         and d.structureID = p.structureID
where 
    d.[date] between '2019-02-12' and '2019-02-12'
    and datepart(dw, d.[date]) not in (1, 7)
    and DistrictCode = 'MA' 
    and FiscalYear = '2019'
    and summerSchool = '0'
    and left(SchoolCode, 1) = '0'
    and e.dayEventID IS NULL
```

Code so far

```
INSERT INTO odb.dayEvent (schoolDay, instruction, attendance, duration, comments, startTime, endTime)
    SELECT 
        d.schoolDay, d.instruction, d.attendance, d.duration, d.comments, 
        d.startTime, d.endTime
    FROM 
        odb.dayEvent e
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        odb.day d ON e.dayID = d.dayID
    INNER JOIN 
        MMSD.vSchoolFromCalendar c ON d.calendarID = c.calendarID
                                   AND d.structureID = c.structureID
    INNER JOIN 
        odb.PeriodSchedule p ON d.periodScheduleID  = p.periodScheduleID
                             AND d.structureID = p.structureID
    WHERE 
        d.[date] BETWEEN '2019-02-12' AND '2019-02-12'
        AND DATEPART(dw, d.[date]) NOT IN (1, 7)
        AND DistrictCode = 'MA' 
        AND FiscalYear = '2019'
        AND summerSchool = '0'
        AND LEFT(SchoolCode, 1) = '0'
        AND e.dayEventID IS NULL
```

Comment: Make sure you have schoolDay column in your dayEvent table

Comment: @MihailShishkov in my select statement, I joined odb.dayEvent with other tables so it inherited those columns. schoolDay is a odb.day column so I just assumed it would be fine ti just put schoolDay as a column. what do i need to change because its says schoolDay is not a column.

Comment: How could anybody know without the table definition? Do you have schoolDay as a column in the DayEvent table?

Comment: @SeanLange schoolDay is a column in odb.day not dayEvent. but in my original select statement it showed up at a column because of my calling a join on odb.day d

Comment: You can't add a value in a column that is non existent in the table for the `insert`  statement. It is not possible, a select statement will not create a field for a table that you inserting with this select. So, what you need to do is either remove the  schoolDay field from the columns list in the insert OR create that field prior to run your insert `alter table odb.dayEvent add column schoolDay .......`

Comment: Look at your insert statement. You are trying to insert into a column named schoolDay which you said does not exist in that table. That of course is going to fail.

Comment: It's a common sense.  How do you expect to insert into column that doesn't exist?  Where do you think the database system is going to put the value of the non-existing column?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer for now, looks like another peace of my code was already solving my questioning issue.....

```
     insert into odb.DayEvent 
        (dayID, type, duration, instructionalMinutes)
     select
        e.dayID, e.type, e.duration, e.instructionalMinutes
    from odb.dayEvent e
           RIGHT OUTER JOIN odb.day d ON e.dayID = d.dayID
          INNER JOIN MMSD.vSchoolFromCalendar c ON d.calendarID = c.calendarID
                 and d.structureID = c.structureID
          INNER JOIN odb.PeriodSchedule p ON d.periodScheduleID  = p.periodScheduleID
                 and d.structureID = p.structureID
       WHERE d.[date] between '2019-02-12' and '2019-02-12'
          and datepart(dw,d.[date]) not in (1,7)
          and DistrictCode = 'MA'
          and FiscalYear = '2019'
          and summerSchool =  '0'
          and left(SchoolCode,1) = '0'
          and e.type IS NULL
     select sts='success', result= convert( varchar,@@rowcount) + ' rows updated.';
     set @rowcount = (select @@rowcount);
```